# Disable products with placeholder image on home page in magento

Tags: magento, random

I use a random code to display products from different categories on the home page on our magento powered shop. This works perfectly. Now I would like to exclude all the products which only have a placeholder image from showing up on the home page. I tried it with the following code:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $categoryID = $this->getCategoryId();
            if($categoryID)
            {
              $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
              $category->load($categoryID); // this is category id
              $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
            } else
            {
              $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
            }
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $collection->addStoreFilter();
            $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 3;
            $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'eq' => ''),
                array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'eq' => 'no_selection')
            );

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work and the products with only the placeholder image do still show up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the 'small_image' filter *after* the collection already has been loaded, so your filter will **not** affect the collection anymore.

Other than that your OR filter looks odd to me. Assumed 'no_selection' is some placeholder image too, then your filter does *accept* placeholder images, where I think you want to *decline* them.

Try to use an AND filter instead:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'neq' => '')
);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array('attribute' => 'small_image', 'neq' => 'no_selection')
);
```